# Regex extracting negative numbers with unknown number format

Tags: python, regex

I'm able to get the numbers out of this string:

`string_p= 'seven 5 blah 6  decimal 6.5 thousands 8,999 with dollar signs $9,000 and $9,500,001.45 end ... lastly.... 8.4% now end`

with this code:

```
import re

def extractVal2(s,n):
    if n > 0:
        return re.findall(r'[0-9$,.%]+\d*', s)[n-1]
    else:
        return re.findall(r'[0-9$,.%]+\d*', s)[n]


for i in range(1,7): 
    print extractVal2(string_n,i)
```

but I can't do negative numbers with it. The negative numbers are the ones in the parenthesis.

`string_n= 'seven (5) blah (6)  decimal (6.5) thousands (8,999) with dollar signs $(9,000) and $(9,500,001.45) end lastly.... (8.4)% now end'`

I have tried to first replace the `()` with a negative sign like so

`string_n= re.sub(r"\((\d*,?\d*)\)", r"-\1", string_n)`

then these to get the negative number

```
r'[0-9$,.%-]+\d*', s)[n]
r'[0-9$,.%]+-\d*', s)[n]
r'[-0-9$,.%]+-\d*', s)[n]
```

And even using a different approach:

```
words = string_n.split(" ")
for i in words:
    try:
        print -int(i.translate(None,"(),"))
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: they are the ones with the brackets... i will modify the question to be more clear

Comment: so questions in () are negative?

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you prefer starting indexing with `0`? It adds complexity to your function, and, as you see in your `range` loop, you have to remember that *this function* adjusts the index. Having it start with `0` makes much more sense – for one, you do not have to test for a negative argument `n`; and, an `n=0` will now return the same result as `n=-1`.

Comment: @usr2564301. There might be a better way, but I adjusted the indexing because a user manually feeds the `n` and it starts with `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your regex to this:

```
import re

def extractVal2(s,n):
    try:
        pattern = r'\$?\(?[0-9][0-9,.]*\)?%?'
        if n > 0:
            return re.findall(pattern, s)[n-1].replace("(","-").replace(")","")
        else:
            return re.findall(pattern, s)[n].replace("(","-").replace(")","")
    except IndexError as e:
        return None    

string_n=  ',seven (5) blah (6) decimal (6.5) thousands (8,999) with dollar ' + \
           'signs $(9,000) and $(9,500,001.45) end lastly.... (8.4)%'

for i in range(1,9): 
    print extractVal2(string_n,i)
```

It would parse the `9,500,001.45` as well - and captures a leading `(` after `$` and before numbers and replaces it with a `-` sign. Its a hack though - it does not "see" if your `(` is without an `)` and would also capture "illegal" numbers like `2,200.200,22`.

Output:

```
-5
-6
-6.5
-8,999
$-9,000
$-9,500,001.45
-8.4%
None
```

You also should maybe think about catching the `IndexError` if your `re.findall(..)` does not capture anything (or too few ones) - and you are indexing behind the list returned.

---

The regex allows:

```
leading literal $       (not interpreded as ^...$ end of string)
optional literal (  
[0-9]                   one digit
[0-9,.%]*               any number (maybe 0 times) of the included characters in any order  
                        to the extend that it would mach smth like 000,9.34,2
optional literal )
optional literal %
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner. One last question. Why does it extract the `,` if the string is `, seven (5) blah (6)  decimal (6.5) thousands (8,999) with dollar signs $(9,000) and $(9,500,001.45) end`

Comment: @jason from the regex there is no prerequesit to have a number before either `',.%'` ... you can change it to `r'\$?\(?[0-9][0-9,.%]*'`

Comment: @PatrickArtner. Sorry I forgot negative percents... could you please modify your answer for ` ,seven (5) blah (6)  decimal (6.5) thousands (8,999) with dollar signs $(9,000) and $(9,500,001.45) end lastly.... (8.4)% now end` please.

Comment: @jason for playing around with regex I recommend:  http://www.regex101.com - put the pattern in the first line, text in the second filed and switch it to _python_ - then play around. Edited for %.

Comment: Why isn't there a website that gives you regex? you give it input and the desired output. It tries until it satisfies your conditions, you give it more conditions to refine it... you would think that would be something someone can program

Comment: @jason Complexity. `[0123456789]{8}` == `\d{8}`  == `\d{7,}` == `\d{6,}` == `\d{5,}` == `\d{4,}` == `\d{3,}` == `\d{2,}` == `\d{,8}` == `\d{,9}`  - all match strings of 8 digits. some better, some worse (`==` : matches ) - but if you want, try it.